# Using function onclick innerhtml

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

I'm stuck with a little JavaScript code, which is supposed to make a variable of my option and send it back. I really don't see where is the problem can someone correct me pls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
  var login = document.getElementById('opt').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('champs1').innerHTML = login;
}
</script>


<div class="row">
    <select>
        <?php foreach ($page->items as $user): ?>
            <option id="opt" onclick="myfunction()"><?php echo $user->getLogin() ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <h3 id="champs1"></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues:

1. You cannot repeat `id`. The `<option>` tags will always have same `id` for all.
2. There's no `click` event for the `<option>`. You should be using `change` event for `<select>`.

The following might work.

```
<select id="opt" onchange="myfunction()">
    <?php foreach ($page->items as $user): ?>
        <option><?php echo $user->getLogin() ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

And change the Script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
  var login = document.getElementById('opt');
  var opt = login.options[login.selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById('champs1').innerHTML = opt.innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Snippet:

```js
function myfunction() {
  var login = document.getElementById('opt');
  var opt = login.options[login.selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById('champs1').innerHTML = opt.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<select id="opt" onchange="myfunction()">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
<div id="champs1"></div>
```

Comment: @Antoine553 Who's saying that? It works for me: https://jsbin.com/bamutijapa/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score -1):

You cannot bind any events to `<option>` element, use `onchange` on `<select>` element instead.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

```php
<div class="row">
    <select id="opt" onchange="myfunction()">
        <?php foreach ($page->items as $user): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $user->getLogin() ?>"><?php echo $user->getLogin() ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <h3 id="champs1"></h3>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
        // get the selected option value
        const selectedOption = document.getElementById("opt").value

        // display the value to UI
        document.getElementById('champs1').innerHTML = selectedOption
    }
</script>
```